# Why do my app web links capture any path on the domain?

Tags: uwp, windows-10

I have a Windows 10 app and a website.  I'd like to use [web app links](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/web-to-app-linking) to allow users to choose to open my app instead of the browser for certain links that they click from, say, an email that I have sent.

After following the directions in that guide I have things set up most of the way.  It even works, and launches my app when I tap/click links to the website urls that I want to redirect to my app instead of opening in the browser.  The trouble is that it *always* works, even on paths where it shouldn't.

The section on the website's JSON file implies that the paths I provide in the JSON file work like a whitelist, while the excluded paths function as a blacklist to filter paths back out.

Using the following JSON file, I would expect to intercept only urls like https://example.com/redirect?foo=bar, but instead I find it capturing all links to my domain.

```
[{
  "packageFamilyName": "<MyPackageName>",
  "paths": [ "/redirect*" ],
  "excludePaths" : [ "/#*", "/shared*" ]
}]
```

Originally I included just the path I wanted to use, assuming that it would be the only one the app intercepted, then I added the excludePaths to try and filter out paths I explicitly didn't want to intercept.  I've tried it with and without leading slashes and trailing asterisks, but none of it works as expected.

Does anyone know why it's overly greedy, and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the culprit was Developer Mode on the phone (Settings -> Update & security -> For developers).  Aside from allowing you to deploy and debug apps, apparently it also causes the phone to give you full URL-intercepting permissions for the domains defined in your deployed app's manifest.  It makes it easier to test out the functionality without needing to actually get something up on the server, but I wasn't expecting it to keep doing that when I actually had the file in place.

The solution, if you want to test real-world behavior, is to turn off Developer Mode.  Switch your phone to "Sideload apps" and have at it!

Just remember to switch it back to full developer mode afterwards or VS will crash on you when you try to deploy your app to the phone again.

Answer (score 0):

A similar answer from: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/672729/view.html

> The behavior you are observing is expected when running on machines
> that are in   Developer Mode. The json file only works on retail
> machines or on machines in “Sideload apps” mode.